# Multithreading with sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is that a normal use for three threads.
Could I use a thread for the GUI Form, one for calculation and the last as a master to kill the others?

Here I start my three thread and when I press ESC key it kill all the processes. Is that a normal way to do it or is it something more elaborate to do?

```
namespace ThreadingTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool exit = false;
        System.Threading.Thread myThread;
        System.Threading.Thread mysecondthread;
        System.Threading.Thread Killingthread;

        myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadLoop));
        mysecondthread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(SecondThreadwork));
        Killingthread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(KillProcess));

        myThread.Start();
        mysecondthread.Start();
        Killingthread.Start();
        while (exit == false)
        {
            var FirstThreadState = myThread.ThreadState;
            var SecondThreadState = mysecondthread.ThreadState;
            var ThirdThreadState = Killingthread.ThreadState;
            Console.WriteLine(ThirdThreadState.ToString());
            if (ThirdThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) exit = true;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        myThread.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine("first thread ended.");
        mysecondthread.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine("second thread ended.");
        Killingthread.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine("third thread ended.");
    }
    public static void ThreadLoop()
    {
        while (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
        {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            Console.WriteLine("I'm working...");
        }
    }
    public static void SecondThreadwork()
    {
        while (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("me too...");
        }
    }
    public static void KillProcess()
    {
    do {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("third ON."); // Do something
        }      
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

    }
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: No, and you don't really want to "guess around" multi-threading - it's quite complex, and it will hurt you. In any case, it's not a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: it`s not common to use directly with the threads, using Thread Pool usually is a good idea.

Comment: Let's ask the question... could we see events as thread pool in iddle mode and waiting an event to start?

Comment: Let's ask the question... could we see thread pool in iddle mode and waiting as an event?